# Facebook Ad Library Ad Snapshot URLs are Broken?

Tags: facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api

I have since figured out how to used cURL on Terminal. When I enter a cURL query with parameters in Terminal, I receive a huge block of un-indented text indicating the ad id, ad snapshot URL, and ad delivery start time. Unfortunately, none of the ad snapshot URLs work.

Facebook says they're supposed to look something like this:
https://www.facebook.com/ads/archive/render_ad/?id=123&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN&gt

Mine look like this (I replaced my access token with Xs):
www.facebook.com/ads/archive/render_ad/?id=215976033116557&access_token=XXXX

Even when I reformat the URL to match that of Facebook's example, the page reads: "This page isn't available
The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed."

Anyone know how to solve this by chance?

Answer (score 0):

Update: exported JSON result to R using rjson, links now work

install.packages("rjson")

library("rjson")

result <- fromJSON(file = "myresults.json")

print(result)

json_data_frame <- as.data.frame(result)

print(json_data_frame)